# How to change the value of a django variable

Tags: python, html, django, for-loop, django-templates

So I have the following array in my source code:

```
values: [
        {
              "Question" :  ["question two"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question 2"]} 
         ,          {
              "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question one"] } 
         ,          {
              "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["another answer to question one"]}
```

I need to render the information as a List view to make it look like this:
question two
 answer to question 2
question one
 answer to question one
 another answer to question one

I'm using Django and HTML for rendering the view, here's my code so far

```
      <div>
         {% with "" as name %}  
         {% for value in view.data.values %}
         <li> 
            {% ifnotequal value.Question name %}
                <div>{{value.Question|default:''}}  {{value.question_creation_date}}</div>
             {% endifnotequal %}
                <div>{{value.user_creation_date}} {{value.Answer}}</div>
         </li>
          <!-- set name equal to value.Question -->
          {% endfor%}
          {% endwith %}
         </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with a for loop:

```
{% with "product" as name %}
    {% for i in products.count %}
        <div>{{name}}{{ forloop.counter }}</div> 
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

Output:

```
<div>product1</div>

<div>product2</div>
```

etc.

---

If you want the counter to start with 0 instead of 1 you can use `forloop.counter0`

Comment: This isn't just a way to achieve it, this is the way it should be done. Variable processing is business logic that goes into the view, rather than the template, thus django's template language doesn't allow complex variable processing.

Comment: ok but how can i also change the variable name to something else and not just do a concatenation

Comment: What do you mean with _something else?_ You can print a Product's attributes for example: `{% for product in Product.objects.all %} {{ product.name }} {% endfor %}`. Like @ChristopherSchäpers said, assigning variables etc. belongs to the view.

Comment: sry i was not clear, i just want to know how to change the value of a variable after it is declared, for example if the value was set to "Product" i want to change it to "Keyboard"

Comment: No that's not possible. What do you want to achieve exactly? Maybe there's a workaround for it.